# Is the White Walker/Other that Samwell Tarly encounters of importance(high-rank)?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

My friends and I were conversing on Team Speak we all came upon this question.  Is it even mentioned in the books?  I know that he was important in the way of knowing White Walkers can be slain, but I am asking if he was of high-rank, or if he was known in a behind the scenes plot of something bigger in say, the current book?

Comment: There has been no sign in the books of white walkers/others having ranks, high or low.

Comment: As far as I recall, the book doesn't mention anything special about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no canon explaining White Walkers, whether they have a society, how it functions etc. The only things we know are things that we've seen, such as that they turn dead humans into [Wights](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wights), and they can be harmed by [Dragonglass/Obsidian](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonglass), and by Valyrian steel. Anything else is just rumours and stories by people in Westeros, such as Old Nan.

According to Melissandre, the White Walkers worship a god known as the [Great Other](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Great_Other). The only source for this is Melisandre, so it's certainly not given as fact. However considering the things we've witnessed from her (and Thoros/Dondarrion), and the fact that the series is titled A Song of Ice and Fire, I'm inclined to believe that she is correct. So assuming that she is, this would suggest that the White Walkers do have some sort of society, so there may be some form of hierarchy amongst them. As to whether or not the White Walker in question is of importance, that's impossible to say.

**So in short, no we don't know anything about White Walker society and hierarchy; so we don't know whether the one in question was considered important.**

***Update based on season 4, episode 4***

> In this episode, something is revealed that isn't yet written in the books. Baby boys (human) are turned into White Walkers by an unknown White Walker, who is believe to be the [Night's King](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Night's_King) due to a [possible spoiler from HBO](http://io9.com/this-accidental-game-of-thrones-spoiler-just-changed-1568796246). There's a number of things we can glean from this, which should give us more information.
>
>
> Firstly (assuming that the HBO spoiler is correct) we now know that the White Walkers have a king, and therefore a hierarchy. Whilst we still can't be certain, we can draw parallels between them and us. Considering that the White Walker that encountered Samwell Tarly was alone, when enemies were nearby, then we can assume that it wasn't high ranking. A King, Lord, General or other does not go out scouting alone. So it's likely that this particular White Walker was a scout, or something like a soldier (or perhaps even operating alone; we don't yet know if the White Walkers are all unified).
>
>
> However if all White Walkers come from human babies, then it stands to reason that there numbers won't be very large (this also makes sense with why they haven't been more brazen with their attacks; and why they convert wights). So in this regard, I'd say all White Walkers are important to them, as they don't have sufficient population numbers to afford to lose many.

So to summarise my hypothesis, I'd say that they are important due to their low population size, but not high-ranking within their hierarchy/society; probably a scout or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and my friends appreciate the context of the answer, not just a no.

Comment: @chax0 hopefully this update will provide more information for you.

Comment: Where did you get the idea about the Night King? As far as I can tell, the creature you refer to is NOT identified by name in the TV series, and it doesn't look much like a king either (sure, there are some spikes on his head, but he looks more like a priest of some sort). Aren't you jumping to conclusions?

Comment: @AndresF. Perhaps jumping to conclusions a little bit, but I'm basing it on the possible accidental spoiler by HBO. It may be a mistake, but it does seem that the character is the Night's King. And the Night's King was mentioned in the book (albeit not confirmed) so it's likely to be correct. I'll edit the answer to clarify. http://io9.com/this-accidental-game-of-thrones-spoiler-just-changed-1568796246

Comment: Oh, ok. I see HBO Go spoiled the name in the info titles. Damn HBO :( Like they say at io9.com, if this is true then maybe most other legends and folk tales from Westeros are also true.

Comment: @AndresF. I'm of the opinion that Old Nan is going to turn out to be very wise and correct; although probably not about the eye of a blue-eyed giant thing, but I have a faint inkling that they might use that as a subtle joke in the closing credits of the final episode. If that does happen, remember I called it here first. :D

Comment: Ahhhh. So that's how the Unsullied feel about those big spoiler blocks. Oh how the mighty have fallen!

Comment: The Night's King in the show is not necessarily the same Night's King from the books. See the discussion [here](http://www.zap2it.com/blogs/george_rr_martin_game_of_thrones_nights_king_not_same_books-2015-06).

Comment: @JeffFerguson perhaps not, but based on the later season 5 episodes he still seems to be of higher ranking than the other white walkers, so I would say that it still provides enough evidence to suggest some sort of hierarchical society.

Comment: @Moogle - did you find any subtle jokes in the final episode?

Comment: @TomGoodfellow not that I can remember. Did you spot any?